# What is the average IQ in Bangladesh or of Bangladeshis?

Tags: iq

In July 2010, Richard Lynn wrote the following in their article "[National IQs calculated and validated for 108 nations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0160289610000450?via%3Dihub)":

> "For example, there was no measured IQ for Pakistan, but there was a
> measured IQ (81) for India. It was assumed that the IQ in Pakistan
> would be approximately the same as in India, and hence Pakistan was
> assigned an IQ of 81."

But in "[A Study of the IQ in Bangladesh](https://mankindquarterly.org/archive/issue/48-1/5)" Published: 2007/09/01 DOI: 10.46469/mq.2007.48.1.5, he wrote:

> "At the time of this compilation we had no measured IQ for Bangladesh,
> so we assumed it would be the same as that of the Indian average for
> which we had a measured IQ of 82. We have now located a study in
> Bangladesh from which a measured IQ for can be calculated at 81."

Does that mean India's reduced by 1 point from 07 to 2010?

And the site [worldpopulationreview.com](https://worldpopulationreview.com/) mentions a score of 74.33 citing Richard Lynn and David Becker which is significantly lower than the two sources above (not linking it as I don't want to give them google juice) and lists Pakistan as having an average IQ of 80 and **Nepal 42.99**.

**Why these findings seem implausible to me.**

Lynn argues a strong correlation between IQ and wealth of nations exist. But,

- Bangladesh's GDP is 416.3 billion USD and Pakistan's 348.3 billion
  USD, and
- Bangladesh's Per Capita Income is 2457 USD and Pakistan's 1505
  USD.

Doesn't that contradict his own findings? And the IQ of 43~ of Nepal is considered in the "mentally retarded range" but they have the per capita income of 1,371.971 USD which is close to Pakistan's where the IQ is supposed to be 80.

Pakistan is a much larger country with a lot of mineral resources while Nepal is a landlocked country. If there hypothesis is correct, then what causes these inconsistencies?

So, my question is, **what is the average IQ in Bangladesh based on sound research?**

Answer (score 3):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

- The average [Intelligence Quotient (IQ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient) in any given country is 100, by definition.
- People attributing an IQ value to countries do not understand the notion of [IQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient), and are likely to be using it to support racist views: better ignore them.

**LONGER ANSWER:**

The concept of [Intelligence Quotient (IQ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient) is to **QUOTIENT** the mental performance on a test of an individual with that of their peers within the same social group, in general individuals of the same age and country.

The concept of [Countries IQ](https://www.worlddata.info/iq-by-country.php) is ill-defined:

> The question of the intelligence of a certain nationality or
> population may be controversial. In fact, intelligence is influenced
> by national, political, and geographic factors.

Such (poorly defined) concept seems to be used mostly to build racist or xenophobic arguments showing the inferiority of some "races" or nations to some others, as in [websites](https://www.worlddata.info/iq-by-country.php) making statements "scientifically proven" without giving any scientific reference:

> Often surprisingly but scientifically proven, a warmer climate badly affects the intelligence quotient.

Better ignore such statements. There are better indicators to compare countries, such as the  [happiness index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_National_Happiness) or the [inequality-adjusted Human Development Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_inequality-adjusted_Human_Development_Index) to cite just a few.

I hope it helps!